# QScrollArea disappears when setting maximum size of a widget inside it

Tags: python, layout, pyqt, scrollbar, qscrollarea

I'm having trouble with a scroll-area which disappears when we try to set the maximum/minimum size of a widget inside it. Is this normal behaviour?

For information, this is how my screen is built:

```
<Splitter>
  <ScrollArea>
    <LayoutOfScroll>
      <Widget>
        <Layout>...
```

and there are a lot of other widgets in the Layout, which are the ones that I am trying to set maximum size for. But when I do set maximum/minimum size on them, they prefer to stack themselves...

I should specify that I already set the `widgetResizable` property to `True` and that if I set it to `False`, the scroll-area is there, but then I can't resize my window because the widgets keep the same size...

How can I set a maximum/minimum size on my child widgets and keep the scroll area.

PS: here is what I've read in the docs of `QScrollArea`, but I don't understand it... It seems to correspond to my case:

> If a scroll area is used to display the contents of a widget that
>   contains child widgets arranged in a layout, it is important to
>   realize that the size policy of the layout will also determine the
>   size of the widget. This is especially useful to know if you intend to
>   dynamically change the contents of the layout. In such cases, setting
>   the layout's size constraint property to one which provides
>   constraints on the minimum and/or maximum size of the layout (e.g.,
>   QLayout::SetMinAndMaxSize) will cause the size of the scroll area to
>   be updated whenever the contents of the layout changes.

Comment: Maybe check this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11386680/gridlayoutscrollarea-widget-position-after-size-change?rq=1) and this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164117/custom-widget-in-scrollarea-is-being-squashed)